# What Google App Engine URL am I supposed to use?

Tags: google-app-engine

In app engine it tells me my URL is projectname.ll.l.appspot.com but if I use projectname.appspot.com that works as well. Which is the correct one to use and why?

Answer (score 0):

**App Engine** is changing the URLs that you use to send requests to your apps. `project-id.appspot.com` is the default URL, however if you have [multiple services and/or versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#urls_for_services_and_versions), each of them will have its own URL.

> Which is the correct one to use and why?

Both are correct, however moving forward you may apply the suggestion from this [release note](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/release-notes#February_11_2020):

> App Engine is changing the URLs that you use to send requests to your apps. URLs now include a region ID to help Google route your requests more efficiently and reliably. For example, an app can receive requests at https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com. This new URL is optional for existing apps and is provided for all new apps.

Comment: What if you code the region URL into your app and change regions later on... project.appspot.com would still work and project.region.appspot.... wouldn't?

Comment: @Mickey Hi OP, you cannot change an app's region after you set it. You may check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations) for your reference.

Comment: Mabel, Thank you. So the only purpose in using the URL with region in it is that it'll load slightly faster than if the non region URL redirects to it?

Comment: @Mickey yes, that would be correct.

Comment: @Mickey if this answer helped, please consider upvoting it so other people can see it first.

Answer (score 0):

You should register your own domain and use that.  The cost is only $12/year so it is affordable even for a hobby project.

If you don't want to do that, then use:

```
projectname.appspot.com
```

because it is much easier to type.

It is possible (though I think unlikely) that this link will stop working at some point and you will need to change to `projectname.ll.l.appspot.com` .  If that is an issue for you, then pay the $12/year to get your own domain.

Comment: I have a domain for the specific project I'm working on. I guess in terms of standardization would it be better to use one over the other? For eg; if I use the project.xx.x.appspot link in my application will it force that region or does it, like the non-region project.appspot.link, just pull it from wherever?